# Format String Vulnerability - Can't read an address from stdin with read() in C

Tags: attacks, buffer-overflow, memory, c, format-string

I wanted to exploit this code using format string vulnerability:

```
int jackpot;

void fmt_str(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    puts("Give me a string to print");
    read(0, buf, 128);
    printf(buf);

    printf("jackpot @ %p = %d [0x%08x]\n", &jackpot, jackpot, jackpot);
    if (jackpot == 0x1337)
        puts("You won!");
    else
        puts("You lost :(");

}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    setbuf(stdout, 0);

    jackpot = rand();
    fmt_str();
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is using format string vulnerability in order to get "You won!". By using `objdump` I found out that the address of the global variable `jackpot` is `0x0804a04c`.
Since i can't use a Python script to input my string in argc, this is what i tried to do (working on gdb):

```
Give me a string to print
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA '\x4c\xa0\x04\x08' BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
```

and this is what i get with `print(buf)`

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA '\x4c\xa0\x04\x08' BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB bffff280 80 0
41414141 41414141 41414141 41414141 785c2720 785c6334 785c3061
785c3430 20273830 42424242 42424242 42424242 20424242 25207825
78252078 20782520 25207825 78252078 20782520 25207825 78252078
20782520
```

Basically, my intention is having the `jackpot`'s address between the 41s and the 42s, so that I can better locate it in the printed string, and perform an attack by changing `%x` to `%n`.
The problem is that with this way of reading input, I can't write the target address in the string, so I can't perform the attack. What do you suggest?
The program is compile with the stack made executable, with -fno-stack-protection and with ASLR disabled.